# error when i tried opening a website with windows.h library

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Opening Google...";
ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"https://www.google.com",NULL, NULL,   SW_SHOWNORMAL);




return 0;

}
```

I get this error: Cannot convert 'const wchart_t*' to 'LPCSTR{aka const char*}\ for argument '2' to 'HINSTANCE_*SHellExecuteA(HWND,LPCSTR,LPCSTR, LPCSTR, LPCSTR, INT)'

Comment: You should be compiling any new Windows application with `UNICODE` defined.

Comment: How would you do that exactly? Never worked on the windows.h library :p

Comment: Depends on the compiler. `-DUNICODE` in GCC and Clang. `/DUNICODE` in MSVC, but there's some project option that I think is on by default nowadays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 capabilities:

1. As @chris noted, you can compile you program with UNICODE defined
2. You can use special macros for string literals for more flexibility

   ShellExecute(NULL, 
                TEXT("open"), 
                TEXT("https://www.google.com"), 
                NULL, 
                NULL,
                SW_SHOWNORMAL);